# How to make Button just works one time

Tags: gui-construction, button

I have such code to slect prefer font

```
fonts = {};
Column[Function[font, Button[font, AppendTo[fonts, 
      font]] -> (Style[ToString[#], 30, FontFamily -> font] & /@ 
      Range[0, 9])] /@ $FontFamilies[[;; 10]]]
Dynamic[fonts]
```

But if I make a mistake, I will click a button more one time somtimes. Then I will get a duplicate element in list `fonts`. Of course I can delete those duplicate element in the list. But I want to know how to make the button just works one time still, is it possible?

Comment: one time ever? at most once per sec? are duplicates never allowed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Details aside, `TogglerBar` seems to fit your needs best:

```
fonts = {};
TogglerBar[
  Dynamic@fonts
, # -> Row[{Pane[#, 200], Range[0, 9]}, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> #, 20}
  ] & /@ $FontFamilies[[;; 10]]
, Appearance -> "Vertical"
]

Dynamic[fonts]
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is better than what I want.

Answer (score 4):

Duplicates are handled automatically if you store the chosen fonts in an assocation.

```
fonts = <||>;
Column[Function[font, Button[font, AppendTo[fonts, font -> 0]] ->
 (Style[ToString[#], 30, FontFamily -> font] & /@ Range[0, 9])] /@ $FontFamilies[[;; 10]]]
Dynamic[Keys[fonts]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a straightforward way to make sure the button only adds the font once. You can so that by adding an `If` statement that checks if the font is already there:

```
fonts = {};
Column[
 Function[font,
   Button[font,
     If[FreeQ[fonts, font, {1}],
      AppendTo[fonts, font]
      ]
     ] -> (Style[ToString[#], 30, FontFamily -> font] & /@ 
      Range[0, 9])] /@ $FontFamilies[[;; 10]]]
Dynamic[fonts]
```